# How to dynamically create an async function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I can dynamically create a function via:

```
new Function(['param1', 'param2'], someRotine);
```

However, how would I go about creating one that's `async`?

I tried

```
new AsyncFunction(['param1', 'param2'], someRotine);
```

but I am getting:

`AsyncFunction is not defined`

I am on node `v14.17.0`.

Comment: `eval('async function() {'+code+'}')` (or the same with `new Function`, if you care about scope) would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation for AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction):

> Note that AsyncFunction is not a global object. It can be obtained with the following code:
>
> ```
> Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor
> ```